# Django: Different views for POST and GET - Form validation errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have a `DemandDetailView(DetailView)` and `BidCreationView(CreateView)`.

On `DemandDetailView` page, there is a form (for creating Bids) which posts data to `BidCreationView`.

I can't figure out what to do in case `form` is invalid. I would like to render `DemandDetailView` again with `form errors` and preserve corresponding URL.

```
class DemandDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Demand
    template_name = 'demands/detail.html'


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bid_creation_form = BidCreationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,request=request)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bid_creation_form']=self.bid_creation_form
        return context

class BidCreationView(CreateView):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    model = Bid
    form_class = BidCreationForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("demands:demands")

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.demand_id = self.kwargs.pop('demand_id')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Do you have any ideas? My only idea is to use session which isn't probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use is_valid() method from Form Objects. Something like:

```
class DemandDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Demand
    template_name = 'demands/detail.html'


def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = BidCreationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,request=request)
    if form.is_valid():
         self.bid_creation_form = form
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['bid_creation_form']=self.bid_creation_form
    return context
```

Option #2 (Personal Choice):

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Bid

class BidCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BidCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs = {"class": "form-control"}

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('user', 'demands', 'amount', 'transaction')
```

Take a look at the Meta class within the Form. Its explicitly calling the Bid Model and the fields attribute is referring Bid fields from the Model Instance. Now you could call this form in any view without calling another view. If you want to add logic to this form, like calculating total amount or something like that then should do it within the form also. Write code once, Dont Repeat yourself.

Comment: This would work If I wanted to post data to url which calls DemadDetailView but I want to send post request with form data to BidCreationView.

Comment: I'm guessing here cause I don't see your Forms.py but following your code, BidCreationForm function is to create a Bid Model instance. This can be done within your forms.py. 

Basically what you want is to extend your form to class form.ModelForm, so it maps your Bid Model Instance. This type of code is super easy to maintain and to scale due your form is already creating the Bid instance from your Model Instance. In this case you can call that Form from any view and create your Bid Instance without explicitly calling a view

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms